# hibernate.AnnotationException: Property of @IdClass not found in entity & This class does not define an IdClass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

```
@NoRepositoryBean
//@Repository
public interface StudentInCourseRepository
//        extends JpaRepository<StudentInCourse, Long>
        extends CrudRepository<StudentInCourse, Long>
{

    List<StudentInCourse> findByCourse(Course course);
}
```

только по @NoRepo проходит компиляция... последствия пока не знаю.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode()
@ToString()
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "student")
@Entity
public class StudentImpl extends Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private Long id;

    private String typeLearn;



@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "name")
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "student")
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private Long id;

    private String typeLearn;
```

промежуточный класс - нужен доступ. таблица создается, но при дальнейшей компиляции при активации репозитория -

```
This class [class com.example.demo.model.learn.StudentInCourse] does not define an IdClass



@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "students_courses")
public class StudentInCourse implements Serializable {

    public StudentInCourse(StudentImpl student, Course course) {
        this.student = student;
        this.course = course;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "fk_id")
    private Long id;

//    @EmbeddedId
//    private StudentIdentity studentIdentity;

    private Integer score = 0;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private StudentImpl student;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private Course course;


 //пробовал разное,  
 @EmbeddedId
 private StudentIdentity studentIdentity; 
//на отдельный класс.
```

может надо вот это? 
    Третья стратегия, GenerationType.TABLE, не зависит от поддержки конкретной базой 
данных и хранит счётчики значений в отдельной таблице. С одной стороны
 это более гибкое и настраиваемое решение, с другой стороны более
 медленное и требующее большей настройки. Вначале требуется создать 
(вручную!) и проинициализировать (!) таблицу для значений ключей:

от 1 до 12  (вот это я не понял)

```
CREATE TABLE JOURNAL
(
    ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE SEQ_STORE
(
 SEQ_NAME VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
 SEQ_VALUE BIGINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO SEQ_STORE VALUES ('JOURNAL.ID.PK', 0);
```

Затем создать генератор и связать его со идентификатором:

```
    @Id
    @TableGenerator( name = "seqStore", table = "SEQ_STORE", pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", pkColumnValue = "JOURNAL.ID.PK", valueColumnName = "SEQ_VALUE", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1 )
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "seqStore" )
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long rowId;
    @TableGenerator принимает кучу аргументов:
```

name — имя этого конкретного генератора
table — имя таблицы, в которой он хранит текущие значения ключей
pkColumnName — имя столбца, в котором хранятся имена значений ключей
pkColumnValue — имя ключа, используемого в этом генераторе valueColumnName — имя столбца, в котором хранятся значения ключей

или нет?
самый нижний способ отсюда:
https://easyjava.ru/data/jpa/pervichnye-klyuchi-v-jpa/
тоже не помог - но ошибка изменилась - меня послали в

```
public class StudentInCourse implements Serializable {

    public StudentInCourse(StudentImpl student, Course course) {
        this.student = student;
        this.course = course;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    @JoinColumn(name = "sc_id")
    private CourseIdentity courseIdentity;

public class CourseIdentity implements Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String studentFirstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String studentLastName;


Property of @IdClass not found in entity com.example.demo.model.learn.StudentInCourse: studentFirstName

org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property of @IdClass not found in entity com.example.demo.model.learn.StudentInCourse: studentFirstName
```

мне обязательно надо в последствии работать с одним полем промежуточной таблицы , чтобы полю не участвующему в связи манитумани засетать инт. который по умолчанию равен 0. есть идеи? способы? или просто через сессию в спринге квайри на таблицу фильтр по курсу - хватать студентов. и каждому полю где студент - ставить оценку.... 
p.s. а таблица то и поля создаются, в идее вижу, трогаю(

CREATE TABLE `students_courses` (
  `courseId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `studentId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `course_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `fk_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`courseId`,`studentId`,`student_id`,`course_id`),
  KEY `FKjgn1a7o3aubvog47ij9cjvgha` (`student_id`),
  KEY `FKcc42107lsifo5rjyjlhdu6i6u` (`course_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

мне нужен будет доступ к полю score. и вообще доставать лист , тоесть DAO класс

Comment: решил сам. короче.